# Existing VM Azure password "Expired" - Did I loose this VM?

Tags: azure

I have an existing VM Azure it seems the password of my XXX user has EXPIRED.

a) I know I have an Administrator user somewhere but how can I ask Azure for its password?
b) I think I read somewhere I could add more admins from the Azure Dashboard, but it was not clear if that was for the VM or for the Subscription. (I surely need for the VM).

I've been on Google for the past 4 hours looking at how can I fix this problem.
I really don't want to believe that MS does NOT offer a way to fix this issue.

At least the Remote Desktop should display a "Change Password" form....

Seriously, did I really lose control of this VM?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option now in https://portal.azure.com/
You need to log in with your Azure credentials.
Browse -> Virtual Machines -> Select Your Virtual Machine 
-> Select Setting on top -> Password Reset

It works... :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the new Azure VM Agent you can do this (as long as the agent is installed, which it is by default on all new VMs you spin up).

You need the Azure PowerShell module for this, which can be downloaded from here:
http://t.co/2hQP6qsGeM

After its installed, fire up PowerShell, connect to your subscription (which is described here: [PowerShell for Azure Documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/)) and issue the following command after replacing the values:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName MyService -Name MyVM | Set-AzureVMAccessExtension -UserName MyUserName -Password "MyComplexPassword123" | Update-AzureVM
```

Comment: Set-AzureVMAccessExtension : Provision Guest Agent must be enabled on the VM object before setting IaaS VM Access. I wonder if there is a way to ENABLE the VM Agent from Powershell??

Comment: There is no cmdlet in PowerShell for it at least. I wonder though, if you save your vm (delete it without destroying the disk) and then spin up a new vm based on that disk if that will let you choose to install the agent. I haven't tried, I'm just talking to myself.

Comment: Just a FYI, its (currently) not possible to install the agent on a existing disk - it has to be done when provisioning the vm for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest solution:

1. Create a script called “ResetPassword.ps1” e.g. with Notepad
2. Add the following line and replace your credentials

   `net user <YourExistingAdminUserName> <YourNewPassword>`
3. Go to the VM in the azure portal
4. Go into the extensions menu for that VM
5. In the top menu pick “Add”
6. Choose the Custom Script extension, create and pick your "ResetPassword.ps1" script file

The file will now be pushed to your VM and deployed. Once it is successfully executed, you can login with the new credentials.

---

Source: http://www.chrisjohnson.io/2018/02/15/domain-controller-in-azure-vm-with-expired-password/#comment-6825733